# Sql DataReader and Multiple Object Variables

Tags: asp.net, arrays, object, highcharts, sqldatareader

I have been trying to figure out this problem all day, and really can't seem to get it. I have a function that I am calling a SQL Stored procedure in, using the SQL DataReader I am returning a table. Now the table has 8 columns but I am only using five per row in what I am trying to do. I have created an object[] called chartInfo and want to fill the object with the five values from the first row and interate through the rows and continue to iterate through the rows filling the object until I reach the end. With the code below it works for the first interation, which gets the values, puts them in an Object Array and I can use it in my chart.

```
SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

Object[] chartInfo = new Object[5];
Object[] chartInfo1 = new Object[4];

if (reader.HasRows)
{
    if (reader.Read())
    {
        chartInfo[0] = Convert.ToDouble(reader.GetValue(1));                   
        chartInfo[1] = Convert.ToDouble(reader.GetValue(2));                   
        chartInfo[2] = Convert.ToDouble(reader.GetValue(3));
        chartInfo[3] = Convert.ToDouble(reader.GetValue(4));
        chartInfo[4] = Convert.ToDouble(reader.GetValue(5));

        //chartInfo1[0] = 500;                   
        //chartInfo1[1] = 20000;                   
        //chartInfo1[2] = 45125;
        //chartInfo1[3] = 68954;
    }
}  
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("No rows found.");
}

reader.Close();

// Declare the HighCharts Object
DotNet.Highcharts.Highcharts charts = new DotNet.Highcharts.Highcharts("chart")
    .InitChart(new Chart
    {
        // Inital Loading of the chart, default is line
        DefaultSeriesType = ChartTypes.Line
    })
    .SetPlotOptions(new PlotOptions
    {
        Pie = new PlotOptionsPie
        {
            DataLabels = new PlotOptionsPieDataLabels
            {
                Enabled = true
            }
        }
    })
    .SetTitle(new Title
    {
        Text = "Overall Sales From Previous Years",
        X = -20
    })
    .SetSubtitle(new Subtitle
    {
        Text = "Source: Sales Database",
        X = -20
    })
    .SetXAxis(new XAxis
    {
        Categories = new[] { "2010", "2011", "2012", "2013", "2014" }
    })
    .SetSeries(new[]
    {
        new Series{ Name = "Carbide(total specials)", Data = new Data(chartInfo), Color = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#FDB813") },
        new Series{ Name = "Test", Data = new Data(chartInfo1) }
    })
    .SetCredits(new Credits
    {
        Enabled = false
    });

ReportChart.Text = charts.ToHtmlString();
```

So my question is do I need to create 5 objects for the five rows, or how would I use the current object array to create populate when the number of rows is unknown, Would I need to supply a for loop to count, I am so confused with this. I hope I have supplied enough info.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So it looks that each row you read is 5 doubles, which you need to store in an array. And then you need to keep a list of all such rows, to pass them all to the chart later.

To store them, you can defined a dedicated class for each row, that is assuming each column makes some business sense. However if it just a value, say a data point, simply use array of doubles:

List chartInfo = new List();

```
if (reader.HasRows)
{
    if (reader.Read())
    {
        double[] rowData = new double[5];
        rowData[0] = Convert.ToDouble(reader.GetValue(1));
        ...
        rowData[4] = Convert.ToDouble(reader.GetValue(5));
    }
}
```

...

And now to use them, create an array of `Series` objects using `chartInfo`. This can be done with for/foreach loop:

```
Series[] series = new Series[chartInfo.Length];
for (int i=0; i< chartInfo.Length; i++)
{
    series[i] = new Series { Data = chartInfo[i] };
}
```

Or with LINQ:

```
Series[] series = chartInfo.Select(c => new Series {Data = c}).ToArray();
```

That will help you handle as many rows as you'd like. However keep in mind that there is still some stuff you need to figure out, like how to display different text and different colors for different rows.